# Local user being removed from Administrator's group and added to Users and Performance Monitor Users Group. NOT on a domain

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

Hello and thanks for reading.  Before I start, I want to state this is happening on machines that are NOT on a domain.  I know there are other answered questions regarding why this might be happening on a machine that is connected to a domain, but this is happening when the machine is just in a WORKGROUP.

I have noticed this on at least 5 or 6 different servers and I have no idea why.  I have a local user account - in the Administrators group - under which several services are running.  At some point - and I can't see any correlation in terms of how long it takes to happen (sometimes days, weeks, months even) - the service starts throwing errors.  When I look into why, I find out that this local account is no longer a part of the Administrators group, but now a part of the Users and "Performance Monitor Users" group.  Sometimes it's also added to a "Performance Log Users" group as well.

I've observed this on Windows Server 2016 and 2019 OSes, as well as Windows 10 Pro.  What's happened twice now is that AFTER I remove the user from these groups and add them BACK to the local Administrators group, the whole thing happens again.  I've Googled this before posting and I can't find anything on this phenomenon.  Why is this happening and how can I prevent it from happening?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find more information about the events.

The Microsoft article
[Audit account management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc737542(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
describes the following two event ids:

```
636 : A member was added to a local group.
637 : A member was removed from a local group.
```

Check if these events are already found in the Event Viewer, under
"Windows Logs > Security".

If the events are not there, check if you need to enable then using the
Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), under
`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy`.
The policy to enable is called "Audit account management" and is described in the above link.

The information in the events might help to identify the process doing this
operation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, this policy setting isn't enabled by default, so I have nothing to review in the Event Viewer.  I did enable it though, so now I guess if nothing else, I'll wait for it to happen again.